# data.table subsetting for bootstrapping

Tags: r, data.table

I am relatively new to `data.table` and was hoping to use the fast sub-setting feature to carry out some bootstrapping procedures.

In my example I have two columns of 1 million random normals, and I want to take a sample of some of the rows and calculate the correlation between the two columns. I was hoping for some of the 100x faster speed improvements that were suggested on the data.table webpage...but perhaps I am miss-using `data.table`...if so, what way should the function be structured to be able to get this speed improvement.

Please see below for my example:

```
n <- 1e6
set.seed(1)
q <- data.frame(a=rnorm(n),b=rnorm(n))
q.dt <- data.table(q)

df.samp <- function(){cor(q[sample(seq(n),n*0.01),])[2,1]}
dt.samp <- function(){q.dt[sample(seq(n),n*0.01),cor(a,b)]}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(median(sapply(seq(100),function(y){df.samp()})),
               median(sapply(seq(100),function(y){dt.samp()})),
               times=100)

Unit: milliseconds
                                                    expr       min        lq    median        uq      max  neval
 median(sapply(seq(100), function(y) {     df.samp() })) 1547.5399 1673.1460 1747.0779 1860.3371 2028.6883   100
 median(sapply(seq(100), function(y) {     dt.samp() }))  583.4724  647.0869  717.7666  764.4481  989.0562   100
```

Comment: My theory: you ARE seeing the effects of the improved sampling, but it is the additional step of running `cor()` on all your samples that is the irreducible time bottleneck.

Comment: Your speed test is a little convoluted. Maybe try `samp <- sample.int(n,n/100); microbenchmark(q[samp,],q.dt[samp])`? I'm seeing the data.table subsetting as about twice as fast with that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @DWin's comment:

If you profile your code you will see that the most costly repeated function calls are those to `seq` (which is necessary at most once) and `sample`.

```
Rprof()
median(sapply(seq(2000), function(y) {     dt.samp() }))
Rprof(NULL)

summaryRprof()

# $by.self
#                    self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
# "seq.default"           3.70    35.10       3.70     35.10
# "sample.int"            2.84    26.94       2.84     26.94
# "[.data.table"          1.84    17.46      10.52     99.81
# "sample"                0.34     3.23       6.90     65.46
# "[[.data.frame"         0.16     1.52       0.34      3.23
# "length"                0.14     1.33       0.14      1.33
# "cor"                   0.10     0.95       0.26      2.47
#<snip>
```

Faster subsetting doesn't help with that.

Comment: Actually you can eliminate `seq()` by doing `sample.int(n, n * 0.01)`